# Can I update BIOS through Windows Live CD?

Tags: bios, windows-live

I was wondering if it would be possible to do it. I have 5 laptops and 3 desktops and non of them run Windows only Linux. Thanks.

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: You have to flash the BIOS. See here ==> http://www.pcstats.com/articleview.cfm?articleID=1605

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if the motherboard manufacturer doesn't provide a way to update the BIOS via Linux you can try using a Windows LiveCD/USB instead. As per my experience though some BIOS updaters do refuse to launch under [WinPE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Preinstallation_Environment) (*should* work fine with [Windows To Go](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_To_Go) but I've never tested this).

However if there is a DOS-based option available I would advise you to use that instead since there's less extraneous stuff involved and thus probably less chance of something interfering with the flashing process. You can follow the instructions [here](http://www.freedos.org/wiki/index.php/USB) to create a FreeDOS LiveUSB from Linux, or simply use [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net) instead:

[image: 1]

Comment: @stejor: You're welcome! Don't know why this question was closed though, seems perfectly clear to me.

Comment: Well you might only take an educated guess :)