# Aspire One 756 BIOS flashing

Tags: ubuntu, bios, acer-aspire

I want to flash the BIOS on an ACER AO756. The [link](http://us.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/drivers) provides 2 versions of the BIOS, both `.exe` files. Which one should I use? I run Ubuntu 12. The battery doesn't charge anymore. I can start the computer without the battery but it stays ON only in the Recovery Menu of Ubuntu. Through this menu I have access to the root shell prompt. I am wondering if there is any test I could run from this prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Install this (Q1VZC221.exe) if the laptop came with Win8 pre-installed:

```
BIOS - UEFI for Windows 8 (Not for Upgrades)    2.21    6.8 MB  2014/04/07
```

Install this (Q1VZC109.exe) in all other cases:

```
BIOS    1.09    7.2 MB  2012/12/11
```

Looks like you'll need Windows running for this (Insyde BIOS/UEFI flasher doesn't seem to provide the option to create a bootable disc/USB). You might possibly be able to run it [from a Windows LiveCD/USB](https://superuser.com/a/906549/138343), but I would not really recommend it.

Comment: The computer has dual boot. It only stays on with with the Ubuntu Recovery Menu displayed. If I try to run normal mode in Ubuntu it shuts itself. If I try to boot in UEFI with Windows it starts the ACER screen but shuts down before displaying anything from Windows. So it might not be a problem with the BIOS. Is there anything I can do from the Ubuntu Recovery Menu that would change the situation?

Comment: Given your description this sounds like a possible hardware problem. Can you check whether a Ubuntu LiveCD/USB works?

Comment: I tried a few times but as soon as Ubuntu starts it shuts itself down. No, I think I will need some help to recover any files on the disk before formatting it from the root shell prompt and then try to install Ubuntu if at all possible. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: So even Ubuntu from a LiveCD shuts down? If that's the case then all I can recommend at this point is to pull out the drive and use it with a USB enclosure on another system to get your data off it.

Comment: Where can I find a good list of basic commands for the root shell prompt to move the files off the drive? I want to try this way first.